# I need a attribute field to be auto generated incrementally. What to do

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have created a FGDB with many layers. Each layer I need a attribute FeatureID. It should be auto generated with increment number. How can I do this?

Comment: Each feature in a file geodatabase table is already allocated a unique ID value (objectid), which is sequentially allocated within each feature class. It's important to distinguish between "layers" which are map display objects, and "feature classes" which are tables in geodatabases (any flavor) or shapefiles. Are you trying to allocate unique IDs across feature classes?

Comment: The ObjectID field is a built in field and does autoincrement, but it is not preserved if you export portions of a feature class or table, so it is not suited to all uses.  If you only plan to use Desktop you can create a long field and use the Attribute Assistant GenerateID capability https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/workflows/configure-generate-id-table/ to automatically update each new record during an edit session.  This field will be preserved by exports.  ArcGIS Pro uses Attribute Rules that aren't the same, but they could calculate the OID into a long field.

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your comments. "Each feature in a file geodatabase table is already allocated a unique ID value (objectid), which is sequentially allocated within each feature class"                                                                     I need another one field called "FEATUREID" as same as the properties of  OBJECTID. When ever i add a feature it should be automatically update this filed with latest number.

Comment: Justin - See my previous answer.  In Desktop Attribute Assistant is the only way to do what you want and during an edit session it can either autocalc the ObjectID value into the FEATUREID field or it can use the GenerateID table to autoincrement the FEATUREID field independent from the ObjectID.  See the link in my previous post.  This approach won't work in Pro, and you would have to use Attribute Rules instead.  No single method will work in both Desktop and Pro.